# Parent and child view in Container V

Tags: ios, xcode, uiviewcontroller

I have a project in iOS and I am trying to modify the same to use in another project. The project is working fine but when I try and Embed the Side View Controller in a tab bar controller it is giving an error

```
**MFSideMenuDemoStoryboard[23760:c07] -[UITabBarController setLeftMenuViewController:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x757a590
2013-06-13 10:08:51.062 MFSideMenuDemoStoryboard[23760:c07] **** * * **Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UITabBarController setLeftMenuViewController:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x757a590'**
```

i understand that there is something wrong in the Code in `appDelegate` .m but can't figure out

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

MFSideMenuContainerViewController *container = (MFSideMenuContainerViewController *)self.window.rootViewController;

UINavigationController *navigationController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"navigationController"];


UIViewController *leftSideMenuViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"leftSideMenuViewController"];
UIViewController *rightSideMenuViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"rightSideMenuViewController"];


[container setLeftMenuViewController:leftSideMenuViewController];
[container setRightMenuViewController:rightSideMenuViewController];
[container setCenterViewController:navigationController];

return YES;
}
```

This is my storyboard

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see in the storyboard and in the exception, your root view controller is a tab bar controller, not a side menu controller.

UITabBarController has a property `viewControllers` which gives you access to the controllers inside the tabBarController. You want to get the controller at index 0. This means the viewController at the first tab.

Something like this should work:

```
UITabBarController *tabBarController = (UITabBarController *)self.window.rootViewController;
MFSideMenuContainerViewController *container = tabBarController.viewControllers[0];
// check that container is actually a container and not something else
NSParameterAssert([container isKindOfClass:[MFSideMenuContainerViewController class]]);
```

Comment: Hi Matthias, thanks for your help , tried this code but it still doesn't bring up the Center view controller, which in this example happens to be the demo view controller, if you can be more elaborate would be of great help. thanks, basically i think the issues is with `code` tabBarController SetView Controllers:

Comment: Hi Finally figured it out, modified the code a bit and got it to work perfectly.

i want to put the final code here for others who may be referencing it later how to do it . the comments section is too small to put them all here.

Comment: @Matthua Bauch

Hi Matthias Bauch, i have another question may be you can help me with it 

[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17531648/implementing-a-split-view-controller-under-a-tab-bar-controller) **bold**

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Your root view controller is not a MFSideMenuContainerViewController. It is a UITabBarController. If you want to use MFSideMenuContainerViewController you will want to check out the documentation: https://github.com/mikefrederick/MFSideMenu/

Here is a basic example:

```
UIViewController *leftSideMenuViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"leftSideMenuViewController"];
UIViewController *rightSideMenuViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"rightSideMenuViewController"];
MFSideMenuContainerViewController *container = [MFSideMenuContainerViewController
                                                containerWithCenterViewController: self.window.rootViewController
                                                leftMenuViewController: leftSideMenuViewController
                                                rightMenuViewController: rightSideMenuViewController];
self.window.rootViewController = container;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

This will replace your existing root view controller with a MFSideMenuContainerViewController and place your old root view controller as the center view controller.

Comment: Yes Patrick, of course this source code is from Mike Fredrick's how to set the rootview controller to UITabbar controller ?

Comment: Maybe I should have been more clear: https://github.com/mikefrederick/MFSideMenu/#basic-setup He tells you right there to set your root view controller to a MFSideMenuContainerViewController. You can't really do this in Storyboards. Best bet is to do it in code, then use your storyboard's instantiateInitialViewController to get your existing controller.

Comment: Hi Patrick, thanks for your help , but it wouldn't work as some more setup needs to be done. if the project is similar  to the example then it would work. i am really new and this is the first project i am starting with iOS. i need to know how to set up the tabBarController as the rootViewController. and since it is tabbar need to declare an array. and need to set up the  parent view controller, container view controller and child view controllers. if you can be more elaborate would be of great help. thanks

Comment: Added a basic example above.

Comment: Patrick the code you have given is for the project using Nib and I am using storybaord. any way thanks a lot for the initiative. got it fixed at last after 4 days of banging with my mac.